# (Python) Is there any advantage to using staticmethods?

Tags: python, static-methods

I was writing a function earlier when my linter recommended I made the method static.
I've always used staticmethods without really knowing what they're for or why they're useful, besides from I can't access any attributes of the current class (since there's no self)

I was just wandering, is there any advantage doing this

```py
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return "bazz"
```

over just doing

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return "bazz"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, not sure how I didn't pass this myself. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the calling of static method does not require to pass a "self" parameter, so - yes, it has an advantage.

Comment: Can you explain more about how not needing to add "self" in the argument list is an advantage? It's 4 characters of typing less. But you need to add the "@staticmethod" annotation at the top so it's a net gain of characters.

Comment: The value of the "self" parameter should be passed to every method call so additional space is required for it in every stack frame. I don't think that it can have a drastic performance impact but in some cases, the increase of stack consumption may be meanful. Especially for the recursions.